# HSE06+SOC calculation in VASP: How to remove false k-points?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, spin-orbit-coupling, hse06

I followed the steps mentioned in the answer of question: [How to carry out HSE06+SOC band structure calculation using VASP](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/how-to-carry-out-hse06soc-band-structure-calculation-using-vasp)
but I found a zigzag band structure. Any idea how to remove false k-points in VASP files directly, because I need projected band structure to plot?

[image: HSE DOS and Band structure]

Comment: Is this perhaps just a matter of not plotting the uniform grid part of the file (which would give you a zigzag) and only plotting the k-points with zero weight that correspond to the actual path of interest? It would be helpful if you provide some additional information such as the KPOINTS file and the plot you are getting.

Comment: @ProfM here  I am attaching band picture and KPOINTS file. Please have a look  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qz5mnNXwxV_k43IHINT83XN6_mVWFsRD?usp=sharing

Comment: @RameshKumar Could you please paste the `KPOINTS` file into a `code` block in the question? I was not able to read it from your Google Drive folder. I've already pasted the other file from your Google Drive folder into the question. I would always recommend trying to put as much information directly into the question rather than in other external places like Google Drive.

Comment: @RameshKumar you can upload your input/output files to Google drive or GitHub and provide a link to it so it can be easy for us to analyse your data.

Comment: @RameshKumar please upload the `KPOINTS` file here: https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters into a folder called 6595 (since that's the number in this question's URL).

Comment: If you want to reply to Chi Kou about this question, you should do so in the comments here rather than one of his other posts.

Comment: Just to re-iterate what others have said, this looks like you've done a density-of-states calculation and then also plotted the eigenstates on that k-point mesh. Since the mesh does not form a 1D path through the Brillouin zone and is arbitrarily ordered, you get these seemingly-discontinuous jump. Try calculating with a few k-points along some high-symmetry lines and plotting those instead.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses suggestions  from the comments.